# AngularJS: search a $scope for a matching value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got a page where I want to print the values of some labels, which I already have in a JSON object:

```
$scope.countries = [
        {
            "key": "NL",
            "value": "Netherlands"
        },
        {
            "key": "BE",
            "value": "Belgium"
        },
        {
            "key": "TR",
            "value": "Turkey"
        },
        {
            "key": "PL",
            "value": "Poland"
        }
    ]
```

So I have the country code in a scope and want to use a filter to replace the code by the actual countryname. Therefore I implemented the filter like this:

```
 {{formulier.country | fetchname }}
```

The filter I'm trying to build should search for the country codes (key) in the countries scope above, and the return the country names for those (value). I started out with this filter, but unfortunately I don't get it to work.

```
app.filter('fetchname', function() {
    return function(input, all) {
        angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(key, value) {
            if (key === input) {
                return value;
            }
        });
    }
  });
```

What alterations do I have to make to my filter, to get this to work in AngularJS? How do I get 'NL' replaced by 'Netherlands'?

Comment: Note that - According to the doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

it's angular.forEach(array, function(value,key){}) not : function(key, value)

Answer (score 5):

The `$scope` in your filter code won't be the same as the `$scope` from your JSON object (I'm assuming; you didn't post all your code). You should update your filter to take an argument, specifically the list of countries used to match against value passed to the filter.

```
app.filter('fetchname', function() {
  return function(input, countries) {
    angular.forEach(countries, function(value, key) {
      if (key === input) {
        return value;
      }
    });
  });
```

You could use it in your HTML like this (given that `countries` is populated for the current scope):

```
{{ formulier.country | fetchname:countries }}
```

Comment: @ruud-kok The above code will also make your code reusable. instead of countries in the filter you can name the variable as values and use it all over your site.